# whose voice the woodland fills

Tags: meaning

From "Sunrise on the Hills" by Henry Wadsworth Longfellow:

> ```
> Came sweetly to the echo-giving hills;
> And the wild horn, whose voice the woodland fills,
> ```

the last line means "the woodland fills the voice of the wild horn"? I am trying to make sense of this sentence, but it doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way around. It means, the horn's voice fills the woodland.

Poetry and song lyrics often twist around normal word order to get a desired rhyme or rhythm. Usually you can figure out what they mean by asking yourself what would make sense. Sometimes it's confusing.